# visual studio code automatic scrolling whenever a character is typed

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, scroll

Visual studio code sometimes automatically scrolls down by a line whenever a character is typed(letter,space, delete). I don't know what caused this problem and I have tried re-downloading but the problem still comes back after a while of usage. This issue has made the editor pretty much unusable. Is anyone else experiencing the same problem or have any idea how to fix it? I use a Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well until I installed the version 1.56.0 update for May 2021. Since then, I have not had any problem with auto-scrolling on each keystroke.

@hzderic - Please confirm that the update fixes your problem so readers can have  confidence in this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue in 2023. Using 1.74.2

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this today using build 1.80.1 (updated 6 days ago).

I found that switching to another editor tab and back again fixed the problem. Annoying, but at least that's an easy work-around.

Comment: not working for me